# Заголовочный файл inttypes.h и его типы данных

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main()
{
    int32_t i_32 = 2147483647;
    int_least32_t i_least32 = 2147483647;
    int_fast32_t i_fast_32 = 2147483647;

    printf("%" PRId32 "\n", i_32);
    printf("%" PRId32 "\n", i_least32);
    printf("%" PRId32 "\n", i_fast_32);

    return 0;
}
```

Можете пожалуйста объяснить в чем разница между данными типами ?

Comment: Форматная константа `PRId32` предназначена для вывода значений типа `int32_t`. Её использование для вывода значений типа `int_least32_t` и `int_fast32_t` _может_ вызывать неопределённое поведение. Для этих типов следует использовать форматные константы `PRIdLEAST32` и `PRIdFAST32` соответственно.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Дополнительные типы данных в C](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1010523).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int_least32_t` это такой тип, который может вместить 32 битное целое с знакомым, но при этом может быть больше 32 бит. К примеру, может использоваться 64-битный `int`. Или 36 битный (вроде есть такие процессоры).

`i_fast_32` аналогично. Вот только компилятор может использовать такой тип, что бы вычисления с ним были максимально быстрые.

Зачем такие типы нужны? Для более явного выражения своих целей. Вполне может быть процессор, который над 80-битными числами считает супер быстро, а остальные типы - за счёт каста (и потери производительности). Используя первый тип мы явно говорим компилятору - нужно что то минимум 32-битное.

В этом всем мне очень нравится то, что обычный `int` не имеет фиксированного размер ни в байтах, ни в битах. а также стандарт никак не называет количества бит в байте. Как то так...

Comment: `least` *(eng)* - **наименьший** тип, который вмещает 32 бита, а не просто может.. "The typedef name int_leastN_t designates a signed integer type with a width of at least N, such that no signed integer type with lesser size has at least the specified width."

Comment: там написано at least, что может быть переведено как "как минимум". Хотя там дальше есть уточнение.